# Access private methods in the rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-console

I'm experimenting with n+1 queries in the rails console, but running

```
> Zombie.include(:brain).all.each do |z| z.brain end
```

Results in this error:

```
NoMethodError: private method `include' called for #<Class:0x000000045bf2a8>
```

Is there anway I can access the include method? A sort of `sudo` method that gives the console access to all of my application's methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm fairly sure you want `includes` there :)

- `includes` comes from ActiveRecord::Base
- `include` comes from Module